# Get the list of objects on a layer in python

Tags: python, scripting, objects, layers

I would like to get the list of objects on a specific layer with python.
When it can be done through iterating `bpy.data.objects[].layers` with `True` value, are there any built-in ways to get what is on a layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no special property or method to retrieve all objects on a certain layer in Blender. There is a context member `visible_objects`, but multiple properties affect it (visibility of object, visibility of layer).

Thus, you should use a plain Python list comprehension:

```
objects_on_2nd_layer = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.layers[1]]
```