# Get list of selected objects on specific layer

Tags: python, scripting, objects, layers

How to find which objects are selected on a given layer?

`bpy.context.scene.selected_objects` shows objects only on visible layer(s). After switching to another layer, the list of selected objects is gone.

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.layers[0] = False
>>> bpy.context.scene.layers[10] = True
>>> bpy.context.scene.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> bpy.context.scene.selected_objects
[]

>>> bpy.context.scene.layers[0] = True
>>> bpy.context.scene.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Cube']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning only the selected objects on a layer simply requires checking the object's `select` property at the same time as checking which layer it is on.

To extend the example on [Get the list of objects on a layer in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15128/get-the-list-of-objects-on-a-layer-in-python):

```
import bpy

layerIndex = 0  #Chosen layer
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

selectedObjects = [ob for ob in objects if ob.layers[layerIndex] and ob.select]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.select = False

layerIndex = 0 
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.layers[layerIndex]:
        obj.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
```

Comment: This will give inconsistent results, in that it can choose objects that are non in the context scene, nor even linked to a scene.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for your comment. You're right. I modified the code. Does this new code work well?