# Meshes won't go away

Tags: python, mesh

In this project: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12514827/broken.blend.html

there are a lot of meshes which won't go away by selecting them and pressing X, aren't selected after selecting by Type and don't even get removed by my program. Why? My only bet atm is to manually rightclick them and delete them one by one, but that can't be the only way, right?

Btw this was the program which hadn't worked:

```
for ob in scene.objects:
    ob.select = ob.name.startswith("VBar")
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: "*don't even get removed by my program*" What does this mean, what program? Is this a question about scripting or Python API? I just selected them here, both by type or *Select All* operator and successfully deleted them. The are single edge meshes placed along the Global X axis of the scene, apparently that makes them unselectable by regular mouse click.

Comment: I added my program to the question, but it got resolved already - it was the layers. Btw I didn't want to select them by mouseclick, but because they somehow went into another layer, I couldn't even select them by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Final]

1. Your meshes are on different **Layer**. Select it or add it (the **Layer**)
   by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>MouseClick</kbd> and you will be able to select them.
2. If you don't see them - as they are just simple lines; press <kbd>Z</kbd> to go to **Wireframe Mode**.
3. For Python solution go here: [Get the list of objects on a layer in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15128/get-the-list-of-objects-on-a-layer-in-python)

Comment: thanks! I failed to realise that they are on another layer, even though they shouldn't have been...